# Debian Squeeze using ext4

Tags: debian, ext4

Does anyone know of any major issues with running debian squeeze using ext4 as the filesystem rather than ext3?  Any known performance or corruption problems?  I need support for files bigger than 2TB. Would XFS or ReiserFS be a better choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ext4 is mainstream. It's stable now, performance is better than ext3 in several types of tests. If you do not have any special requirements, you should use it.

Comment: I agree. I have used ext4 for / in squeeze. Important note, however, there is a problem with grub-legacy and ext4 in squeeze, so stick to ext3 for /boot if you are using grub-legacy.